# Javascript: Creating a Shopping List Using Web Storage

Tags: javascript, html, function, web-storage

I have the following exercise question that I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around:

[image]

So far I've started the code off as such:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
 <script>
  function addItem(){
   var form = document.getElementById("form1");
   var item = form.elements["name"].value;
   var cost = form.elements["price"].value;
   
   //what should I do next?
  }
  
  function removeItem(){
   //remove item code here
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1">
  Item Name: <input name="name" type="text">
  Item Cost: <input name="price" type="text">
  <button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="removeItem()">Remove</button>
 </form>
 <div id="div1">
  <ul id="ul1">
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the basic structure of how I want my page to look. I know that I will have to create two functions that will handle the add item and remove item criteria in the question. However, I'm sort of lost at the point where I have to save the user's input. I know that I have to use web storage and possibly an array? How should this be coded?

Would appreciate any insight. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Source: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)